# Does Kernel HWE 4.18.0-13 support overlay nfs_export=on?

Tags: kernel, nfs, btrfs, overlayfs

I have a problem nfs exporting an overlay of btrfs and ext4. The overlay works, but even though it is mounted with `nfs_export=on` I get the error message:

```
exportfs: /data/merged does not support NFS export
```

this is my export:
`/data/merged 192.168.0.0/255.255.255.0(ro,fsid=1,async,insecure,crossmnt)`

`uname -a = 4.18.0-13-generic #14~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 6 14:09:52 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

So how can I find out if the nfs_export feature is supported by that kernel? Generally it was introduced in 4.16 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if the `overlay` module support the NFS feature you can run `modinfo overlay`.

```
root@host:~# modinfo overlay | grep nfs
parm:           nfs_export:bool
parm:           ovl_nfs_export_def:Default to on or off for the NFS export feature
```

That should print lines containing NFS. Additionally you have to enable other `overlay` features as well.

- `-o index=on`
- `-o index=on -o redirect_dir=nofollow` when there is no `upperdir`

Comment: got it. feature is availble and additional options make that work :)